# Datatables fix second row

Tags: javascript, datatables

I started using datatables for my tables.
I now have a table with customers.
The first row is the table header. The second row is for a button to add a new customer.
The rest of the rows is the list of customers.

I want datatables to sort everything but not the "new customer" row. How to lock this row / exclude it from sorting?

Tried this:

```
<table class="muitable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" id="customertable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
            </th>
            <th>
            </th>
            <th class="muitable bluehover hand" >
                        Name
            </th>
            <th class="muitable bluehover hand" >
                        Created
            </th>
            <th class="muitable bluehover hand" >
                        Status
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <th width="16">&nbsp;
            </th>
            <th class="muitable hovernextcell" onclick="newcustomer()">
                        <img src="/common/images/plus.png" width="16" height="16" class="hand">
            </th>
            <th class="muitable bluecell">
                        New customer
            </th>
            <th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>   
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    --contents--
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem that arises now is that the "sorting buttons" are all over the place. When there is a value in the cell on the second row, this becomes the button, if theres not, it uses the first row for making a sorting button.

How to tell datatables to leave the second th row alone and just use the first row as headers?

Comment: Please review the [HELP](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help) section before posting. Per the flagging menu: _"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a **minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question [checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)."_...

Comment: Sorry, edited the post. Please help me out now.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the "Add Customer" button in the header. Something like this:

```
 <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>etc</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">
                <button>Add Customer</button>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Now dataTables will not sort the row.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fd3ED/

Comment: I edited the original post, please review it. If I use your trick, the sorting "buttons" are created on the second row, now the first row with the actual headers..

Comment: @Mbrouwer88 I've update Icarus's jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bluegeek9bluegeek9/Fd3ED/1/  The sorting buttons are on the first `TH`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by by using two header rows and using the option http://datatables.net/ref#bSortCellsTop